# Elasticsearch: Get the ordering number of a specific item

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Among companies in the same industry, I need to take the top 5 companies with the highest revenue, and which particular company ranks in that industry.
It is easy to write the first query:

```
GET myIndex/_search
{
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 5, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "industryCode": "xxxx"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "revenue": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I don't know how to write the second query. Currently, I have to use the scroll function to scan all records of companies in the same industry, like this:

```
async Task<int> GetRank()
{
    int rank = 0;
    searchRequest.Size = 500;
    searchRequest.From = 0;
    searchRequest.Scroll = "1m";

    var rs = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Tmp>(searchRequest);

    while (rs.Documents.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in rs.Documents)
        {
            rank++;
            if (item.OrganCode == request.OrganCode) return rank;
        }
        rs = _elasticClient.Scroll<Tmp>("1m", rs.ScrollId);
    }

    return rank;
}
```

This approach is really very slow, if the company has very low revenue, it may take several minutes to produce results. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the top 5 companies with the highest revenue, grouped by industry code. This can be done with a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation and a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub aggregation

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "industry_codes": {
      "aggs": {
        "top_companies": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 5,
            "sort": [
              {
                "revenue": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "industryCode"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

In NEST, this would look something like

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<Tmp>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("industry_codes", t => t
            .Field(f => f.IndustryCode)
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .TopHits("top_companies", th => th
                    .Sort(so => so
                        .Descending(f => f.Revenue)
                    )
                    .Size(5)
                )   
            )
        )
    )
);
```

To get the top hits for each industry code

```cs
var termsAgg = searchResponse.Aggregations.Terms("industry_codes");

foreach (var bucket in termsAgg.Buckets)
{
    var topHits = bucket.TopHits("top_companies");
    
    foreach (var company in topHits.Documents<Tmp>())
    {
        // do something with company        
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I want to find out the company's ranking of revenue in the industry. I have found a solution, just count the number of companies with higher revenue, and plus 1

Comment: I can see two possible interpretations of what "company's ranking of revenue in the industry" actually means: 1. group companies by industry and sort each group by revenue descending, providing a rank per industry. or 2. sort all companies by revenue descending to provide a rank, then group them by industry to find the global rank of the top five companies in each industry. It might be worth elaborating on what is required in the question.